# Closed, Convex, Absorbing and Balanced Spaces contain a neighborhood of zero.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, solution-verification, proof-explanation, convex-analysis

I am stuck on proving the following lemma:

> Let $E$ be a Banach space and $0 \in B \subseteq E$ satisfy: 1. $B$ is closed 2. $B$ is convex 3. $B$ is "balanced" i.e. $\lambda B \subseteq B$ for all $|\lambda| < 1$. 4. $B$ is "absorbing" i.e. for all $x \in E$, there exists $\lambda > 0$ such that $\lambda x \in B$. Then $B$ contains a neighborhood of $0$. Note in this case neighborhood means an open set containing $0$.

My attempt so far:

Let us write $E = \bigcup_{n = 1} ^\infty nB$. This is possible because $B$ is absorbing and $E$ is a vector space. Then by the Baire's Category Theorem, there exists some $n \in \mathbf{N}$ large such that $B(x_0, r) \subseteq nB$ for some $x_0 \in nB$ and $r > 0$. Now if $B(x_0, r) \subseteq nB$, then $-B(x_0, r) \subseteq n(-B) \subseteq nB$ as $B$ is balanced. **Now I want to use convexity to show $B(0, r) \subseteq nB$ and so $B(0, \frac{r}{n}) \subseteq B$.**

However, I am not quite sure how to fill in the gap for this last part.

Comment: I take that $E$ is complete, correct? Otherwise, you wouldn't be able to use the Baire Category Theorem. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @TylerMasthay Yes, I will update the post.

Comment: The statement is false if we consider $B = \{0\}$, right? So in the very least, you need to modify your setup to have $0 \in B$ and also there exists $x \neq 0$ such that $x \in B$.

Comment: @TylerMasthay $B = \{  0 \}$ can not be the case because it is not absorbing (condition 4), I think? Given $x \not= 0$ and $x \in E$, we can not necessarily find $\lambda > 0$ such that $\lambda x \in B$.

Comment: Sorry, yes you're right; I missed condition (4)...I thought you only had three conditions up there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\|x\| <r$ Then $x+x_0 \in B(x_0,r) $ so $x+x_0 \in nB$. Also $x_0 \in nB$ and $-x_0 \in nB$ by symmetry of $B$. Hence. $x=(x+x_0)+(-x_0) \in nB+nB \subseteq 2nB$ by convexity of $B$. It follows that $B(0,\frac r {2n}) \subseteq B$.

[Proof of $nB+nB \subseteq 2nB$: $nb_1+nb_2=2n (\frac {b_1+b_2} 2) \in 2n B$ for all $b_1,b_2 \in B$]